# x64 ZeroMQ jzmq build process for Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit, zeromq

Trying to build jzmq for mw windows 7 (64 bit) following the instructions found here:
[http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:java](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajava) (there's a section at the bottom specific to Win 64 machines)
When I reach step 5 "With NSIS installed you can jump to build the package or just build the libraries." I receive a long list of unresolved external symbols after 100% build:
For example:

```
Linking CXX shared library lib\jzmq.dll
Creating library lib\jzmq.lib and object lib\jzmq.exp
Context.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _zmq_errno reference
d in function _Java_org_zeromq_ZMQ_00024Context_construct@12
Socket.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zmq_errno
Context.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _zmq_init referenced
 in function _Java_org_zeromq_ZMQ_00024Context_construct@12
Context.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _zmq_term referenced
 in function _Java_org_zeromq_ZMQ_00024Context_finalize@8
Poller.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _zmq_poll referenced
in function _Java_org_zeromq_ZMQ_00024Poller_run_1poll@24
```

I have C:\zmq\zeromq-3.2.2\lib\x64 set in my system path variable. and I modified CMakeLists.txt at line 101 to point to my zeromq-3.2.2 dirs i.e.,

```
include_directories(
#   /zeromq/zeromq-2.1.10/include
    /zmq/zeromq-3.2.2/include
    ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
link_directories(
#   /zeromq/zeromq-2.1.10/build/lib
#   /zeromq/zeromq-2.1.10/build64/lib
    /zmq/zeromq-3.2.2/lib/x64
)
```

I think there's another path variable missing or something inside my CMakeLists.txt is pointing to the wrong location, but at the moment I'm not sure what I should be looking for.
Any assistance getting my jzmq to build would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Visual Studio 2010 pro instead of CMake. I set up a new build configuration for x64 and copied all the 32 bit setting, then made sure to define the library and resource variables to their locations, and it built no problem. Sorry CMake, better luck next time.